# Специалист по c# и unity

Tags: c#, unity3d-android

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Написал код для того что бы кот собирал монетки и она начислялись слева в тексте но они не начисляются то есть кот их собирает монетка удаляется после того как кот ёё собрал но в текст не начисляется что кот ёё взял. предоставил два кода. код который на монетке coin и который на тексте suma прошу помочь. может знаете как правильно написать или исправить ошибку.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Пожалуйста, оформляйте код правильно

Comment: Приведите код текстом, а не картинками.

Answer (score 1):

При взятии монетки прибавляется к переменной объекта монетки, который сразу удаляется. Вам надо привязать её. А лучше сделать отдельный тэг и в коде игрока проверять столкновение и тэг объекта. Например:

```
void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D coll){
    if (coll.transform.tag == "money"){
        money++;
        UpdateText();
    }
}
void UpdateText(){
    SumaMoney.text = money.ToString();
}
```